# Show this indicator during regular market hours only

Tags: pine-script

How can I modify my following indicator to only show during regular market hours of 0930-1600 and not during pre and post market?

```
//@version=2
study("Percent Lines", overlay=true)

markethours = "0930-1600", dailyopen = "0930-0931"

openprice = time("1", dailyopen) ? open : time("1", markethours) ? openprice[1] : na



line15  = plot(openprice * 1.15)
line25 = plot(openprice * 1.25)
line50 = plot(openprice * 1.50)
```

in this picture I only want the horizontal lines, not the diagonal lines outside of regular market hours. Would appreciate any help. Thanks
[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line` style works that way. You can use `circles` instead:

```
//@version=2
study("Percent Lines", overlay=true)

markethours = "0930-1600", dailyopen = "0930-0931"

openprice = time("1", dailyopen) ? open : time("1", markethours) ? openprice[1] : na

line15  = plot(openprice * 1.15, style=circles)
line25 = plot(openprice * 1.25, style=circles)
line50 = plot(openprice * 1.50, style=circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, that makes sense because the code tells me it should only be visible across the specified market hours of 0930-1600 but it doesn't, really grateful for your help